# How to get an loading gif image when we use infinite scroll in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose if the data is more and we keep a infinite scrolling with infinite-scroll-distance=2 ,when ever the data is loading a image of loading gif must be displayed ..Is it possible to do ..Can i have any example for it ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/U7Bz9/3327/ can anyone help me to implement that loading gif in the above fiddle

Comment: you can refer this link http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-hide directive for this. You need to add loading image which will work as per content load on-top of ng-hide

**Angular Code**

```
function Main($scope) {
$scope.items = [];
$scope.showLoader = false;
var counter = 0;
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({id: counter});
        counter += 10;
     }
    $scope.showLoader = true;
  };    
    $scope.loadMore();
}

  angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
      var raw = elm[0];

      elm.bind('scroll', function() {
        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
            scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
        }
      });
   };
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
    </ul> 
    <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif" ng-hide="!showLoader"/>        
 </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/LedkLocL/
Hope this helps you.